# I want to change the key binding for Tab key for a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, key-bindings

Here is my code for customizing the key binding but this doesn't seem to work. It works for other keys (I tried it with key M) but whenever I press TAB focus shifts to next component instead of showing message dialog with "Hello" text.

```
JButton button= new JButton();
     button.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB,0),"sayHello");
button.getActionMap().put("sayHello", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hello");
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd be very careful about modifying the actions of "known" key strokes, as you are affecting the user's experience and comfort

Answer (score 2):

Tabbing is handled by the focus manager so the Tab key is intercepted before the Key Bindings are processed.

Try removing the Tab key from the focus manager when you create the button:

```
button.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, null);
//button.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, null);
```